# How to use different API endpoints for two different production builds?

Tags: vue.js, production-environment, vue-cli-3

I need to generate two production builds. One for staging and one for final production. I use `vue-cli-service build` to create a build. What I need is to make two npm scripts which will use different API endpoints for different conditions.

Below is the file where I export my api endpoint.
`src/config/index.js`

```
import dev from "./dev.env.js";
import prod from "./prod.env.js";
let api
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  api = dev
}
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "finalprod") {
  api = prod
}
export default api;
```

And in the `package.json` script I have

```
"build": "vue-cli-service build",
"buildprod": "NODE_ENV=finalprod vue-cli-service build",
```

This seems to solve the problem.
But the issue with this is that, when the environment is changed to `finalprod`, then the `build` command doesn't generate a **production** build.

Also I checked [this url](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#modes), but couldn't get my solution from this.

### Note:

1. I don't have CI/CD setup, so I don't have any env in the server. I just create a build on my local and use `ftp` to upload the build to server which serves static files.
2. I initiated the project using command `vue create project-name`

Answer (score 3):

Here's one solution you can try to solve it.

1. In your vue project root, create an env file: `.env.finalprod.local`

> Inside your env file, you should declare `NODE_ENV=production` so that
>   it will built in production-mode.
>
> If you want to specify other custom environment variables, make sure
>   to prefix it with `VUE_APP_`, otherwise, it will be ignored on build.

Here's what it should look like:

```
NODE_ENV=production
VUE_APP_API_ENDPOINT=YOUR_API_ENDPOINT_HERE
```

This means you have to define separate env files for the other environments such as `.env.development.local` and `.env.production.local` if they use different API endpoints.

2. Modify your `src/config/index.js` similar to the codes below

```
let api = process.env.VUE_APP_API_ENDPOINT;
export default api;
```

3. In your `package.json`, change your script to this:

`"buildprod": "vue-cli-service --mode finalprod"`

This will build a production app in staging mode which will use .env, .env.finalprod or .env.finalprod.local if they are present.

Note that if you have this script `"buildprod": "vue-cli-service --mode finalprod"`, you have to name your .env file using `.finalprod` as well, example `.env.finalprod.local`, otherwise the cli cannot find it and will not build not your app in production mode.